# Add a group of messages to console sidebar in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

By any chance is it possible to add a group like "Errors", "Warnings", "Info" into the console and filter my messages by it?

[image: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/reference]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) on `console`, you have several commands for these tasks:

```js
console.error("This is an error");
console.info("This counts as info");
console.warn("This is a warning");
console.log("General logging");
```